# How to use multiple Gulpfiles in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp

We have a lot of automation in out projects. Now with visual studio 2015, we decided to use gulp for this purpose.

Since we have a lot of tasks, is there a way to create multiple gulpfiles in a single project?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the same thing some time ago. I used the following article as a guide.

http://macr.ae/article/splitting-gulpfile-multiple-files.html

Hope it helps.